# Can't Run PHP cURL in IIS Web App, But Can From CLI

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-7, curl, iis-7.5

I'm running 5.2.14 with IIS on Windows 7. Used the Windows Platform Installer.

When I write a script that uses cURL or file_get_contents() and run it via the commandline, everything works great.

If I use the same code in a web page, running in IIS, the request always fails. cURL returns a response code of 0. file-get_contents comes back with "Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known". I even tried putting the code in a separate script and running it via exec() to pipe the output back to my web script. But the script, which works fine from the CLI, fails when called by a PHP script being executed by IIS.

php.exe -i returns no errors. phpinfo() run via IIS in a web page shows the same active/activated cURL as in php.exe -i. My libeay.dll and ssleay.dll libraries are all over my path.

There doesn't seem to be a problem with cURL itself. My best guess is that this is a firewall thing or a permissions thing, where IIS runs PHP as a guest user who is blocked from network access, but when I run it from the commandline, I'm not blocked.

I don't know enough about configuring IIS or the firewall or security policies to figure out where to change things and I don't want to accidentally open up a big hacker tunnel into my system by just randomly lowering security until something clicks. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> "Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known".

That's your clue, No such host is known, try a raw IP address see if that works, if so then it's because PHP can't see hosts basically IIS isn't passing that info in perhaps.

Comment: Tried that. Just another error about the connection. Seems the host resolution error is a symptom of the lack of network access. I also disabled the Windows firewall and got the same errors. The issue seems to be that network access is being denied to the user IIS runs PHP as based on some other setting.